# Many tables or one table in Azure TableServiceContext file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm working on creating an Azure application which would use around ten ttorage tables. I would like to adopt best practices but I am not sure if I should have just one single file with all the tables in the dataservicecontext.cs file or if I should have a different file for each table. Looks to me like both ways achieve the same thing. Anyone else have an opinion on what would be the best practice?

```
public class ContactDataServiceContext
    : TableServiceContext
{
    public ContactDataServiceContext(string baseAddress,
        StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }

    public const string ContactTableName = "ContactTable";

    public IQueryable<ContactDataModel> ContactTable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<ContactDataModel>(ContactTableName);
        }
    }

}


namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    public class NerdDinnerDataContext : TableStorageDataServiceContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Define an entry-point into our table.  Dinners represents an "EntitySet".
        /// </summary>
        public DataServiceQuery<Dinner> Dinners
        {
            get
            {
                //Create the root of a LINQ query of type Dinner against the table Dinners
                return this.CreateQuery<Dinner>("Dinners");
            }
        }

        public DataServiceQuery<RSVP> RSVPs
        {
            get
            {
                //Create the root of a LINQ query of type RSVP against the table RSVPs
                return this.CreateQuery<RSVP>("RSVPs");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the code above. I can't seem to get it to show correctly. What I meant to show was two files doing more or less the same thing. I know the latter uses an obsolete library but it still shows combining more than one table within the file.

Comment: Thank you Mark for taking the time to fix my format problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me this just comes down to code maintainability.  If you favor many classes so that one class size does not grow too big, then splitting these out into separate classes might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There typically isn't much implementation to a table, so I think it's a bit messy to have a file per table and partial classes. You would want to group them logically so I'd recommend creating a file per Context with it's associated tables.